Justification of the induced orientation on a sub-manifold with boundary
In my study of orientation of sub-manifold, I tried to construct the induced orientation on the boundary of a sub-manifold and I would like to have your advice because in the book I have (Milnor’s topology from the differentiable viewpoint) the exposition is too concise to verify if the details of my idea are correct.
We start with $M$ a $m$ dimensional sub-manifold with boundary that is oriented. We denote $\pi_x$ this choice of an equivalence class (for the equivalence relation that defined orientation in a vector space) for each tangent space $TM_x$ for $x\in M$.
Now we observe that $TM_x = T\partial M_x \bigoplus (T\partial M_x)^{\perp}$. If we consider $w$ a basis of $TM_x$, we know that it can be decomposed as being one term basis vector of $(T\partial M_x)^{\perp}$ and  $m-1$ terms that form a basis in $T\partial M_x$. The later being of dimension $1$, if we consider a local parametrization $g$ at a neighborhood of $x$, we know that $dh_x$ allows to define, through coordinate, inward and outward vector of $(T\partial M_x)^{\perp}$ by taking respectively $dh_x(w_m)$ and $-dh_x(w_m)$ where $w_m$ is a basis vector of $(T\partial M_x)^{\perp}$. We  denote $\eta_x$ the outward vector that is the one with $m$-th coordinate being negative.
The induced orientation of $T\partial M_x$ is then the equivalence class $\tilde{\pi}_x$ defined by
$$
v\in\tilde{\pi}_x\iff (v,\eta_x)\in\pi_x
$$
However when I want to verify that this definition is consistent I have some trouble :
If we consider $v,v’\in\tilde{\pi}_x$ we know that $\det(P)>0$ where $P$ is the change of basis matrix from the basis $w=(\eta_x, v)$ to the basis $w’=(\eta_x, v’)$.
Now we observe that this matrix is triangular by the fact that we have decomposed $TM_x$ as an orthogonal direct sum. We denote $A$ this sub matrix of $P$ that is the change of basis matrix from the basis $v$ to the basis $v’$ (obtained by removing the last line and the last column). A well know property of the determinant gives us that
$$
\det(P)=\det(A)\text{sign}(\eta_x)>0
$$
I would like to conclude that $\det(A)>0$ but it suffices to impose that $\text{sign}(\eta_x)=1$, that is the choice of an orientation for $(T\partial M_x)^{\perp}$.
I would like to know if this construction seems correct to you please

First, to get signs right (particularly for Stokes's Theorem, not in Milnor's book), you need to put the outward normal first, and then follow with an ordered basis for $T(\partial M)_x$. Second, the vector $dh(w_m)$ is complementary to the tangent space of the boundary, but is very unlikely actually to be normal (i.e., orthogonal to the tangent space of the boundary). Notice that you have not followed Milnor carefully in either of these definitions.

@TedShifrin Thank you a lot for your comment ! You are right on these two points indeed. By trying to get everything clear I did some mistakes on these definitions that I can fix I think. Does the rest makes sense to you ?

The $\text{sgn}(\eta_x)$ makes no sense, but the overall idea is correct. You need to make various corrections in order to have a correct proof.

@TedShifrin Oh yes you are right, I was sloppy on this. Thank you a lot I will try to make the necessary modifications !

@TedShifrin I think that my approach to prove that the change of basis matrix $A$ has determinant positive is not the good one because I cannot give a meaning to the determinant of $\eta_x$ as it is a vector… have you an other way to prove it in mind ? Thank you for your help !
